# Interpolate: spectra (wavelength, counts) at a given temperature, to create grid of temperature and counts

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, scipy, interpolation

I have a number of spectra: wavelength/counts at a given temperature. The wavelength range is the same for each spectrum.

I would like to interpolate between the temperature and counts to create a large grid of spectra (temperature and counts (at a given wavelength range).

The code below is my current progress. When I try to get a spectrum for a given temperature I only get one value of counts when I need a range of counts representing the spectrum (I already know the wavelengths).

I think I am confused about arrays and interpolation. What am I doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

image_template_one = pd.read_excel("mr_image_one.xlsx")

counts = np.array(image_template_one['counts'])
temp = np.array(image_template_one['temp'])

inter = interpolate.interp1d(temp, counts, kind='linear')

temp_new = np.linspace(30,50,0.5)
counts_new = inter(temp_new)
```

I am now think that I have two arrays; [wavelength,counts] and [wavelength, temperature]. Is this correct, and, do I need to interpolate between the arrays?

Example data

[image]

Comment: can you give a simplified example of the contents in mr_image_one.xlsx?

Comment: Example data added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to achieve can be done with interp2d:

```
from scipy import interpolate

# dummy data
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'temp': [30]*6 + [40]*6 + [50]*6,
    'wave': 3 * [a for a in range(400,460,10)],
    'counts': np.random.uniform(.93,.95,18),
})

# make the interpolator
inter = interpolate.interp2d(data['temp'], data['wave'], data['counts'])

# scipy's interpolators return functions, 
# which you need to call with the values you want interpolated.    
new_x, new_y = np.linspace(30,50,100), np.linspace(400,450,100)

interpolated_values = inter(new_x, new_y)
```